# library module and google-services.json files

Tags: android

I am already using an application(has app module) which uses conversations.im as the base. This application has free, paid etc product flavors and debug and release build types. This project already has firebase integration and has 2 applications integrated. I have one google-services.json file in the root directory of the app module.

Now I want to move away from conversations.im(ejabber) and want to implement a separate chat component using cloud firestore. I have created this component as an android library module which I will use in my existing app module.

I want to have separate chat data for this chat library for debug and release types. This will require me to have unique application ids for this library module. But documentation says I cannot have applicationId in a library module.

I am confused where to keep the google-services.json files, in library module or in the app module which will use the chat library module. Looks like can't keep in library because of limitation. And if I keep in app module, library chat module can't work as a separate module in itself.

How should I go about this setup so that I could use different google-services.json files for debug and release types and at the same time make this new module as a library.

Answer (score 0):

Logically speaking, any android project should be able to use the library module and all the chat data should belong to the project and not tied to the chat library. If I go by this approach, google-services.json files should reside within the app module and not library module.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that we don't have to put the google-services.json file in the library module. We can keep them in the app module which uses the library module.

Now the next question is, is it possible to view data sent from different build variants of the same app under different application views so that we don't accidentally corrupt the test data and production data in firestore?

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted this.

I had to create separate project to keep my firestore chat data for staging and production separate. This is because firebase console does not show the firestore chat data application wise. It shows the chat data project wise. Therefore irrespective of your app's build-variants, data will always flow into one firestore db. And just in case we want to keep our test and production data clean, creating a new firebase project is the only way out.

Thanks everyone for reading the question.